# Making Images Viewed By UIWebView Smaller

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, nsdata

i have a list of entries from a database and I'm feeding them in to HTML to a UIWebView that is making a list of the database entries on the page.
(Much Easyer/Better then extending UITableView Cells)

My Problem is with UITableView i was able to grab an image on a server as NSData and with UIImageJpegRepresentation set the quality for the image a bit lower to be better on the iPhone's cellular downloads.

Now i can go and grab an image from the server as NSData Compress the image then convert it to base 64string and spit it into the WebView but is there any other way to do this?

TLDR: How can i decrease the size of images seen in a HTML Page?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII drugs are _never_ the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by feeding the page i was going to visit to a web service. The web service then returns a set of images compressed at lower quality.

Because the only pages the app is going to visit were my own with user avatars and stuff i was able to profile what images would be needed.

On the iPhone i rebuilt the webpage with the set of those smaller images in a UIWebView.

So in the end i downloaded less cellular data and problem is solved.